# Mean of data.frame data condtional on one row and one column in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, mean

I have a data.frame of the following form:

```
r1 <- c("a", 1, 2, 5, 6,11, 1 )
r2 <- c("b", 4, 2, 7, 6,3, NA )
r3 <- c("b", 14,NA , 5, 6,3, 1 )

df2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(r1,r2,r3))
colnames(df2) <- c("type", 1,2,3,1,2,3)

df2
```

I wish to calculate mean of all numeric variables in the matrix conditional on "type" as well as on the column names (1, 2, 3 respectively).

Note, that since there are `NA`'s in the data.frame, I can't using `rowMeans` (or alternatively, `colMeans`).

The data.frame (or matrix) I am hoping to get is something like

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
a  3.5  6.5  3.0
b  7.5  2.7  4.3
```

Please let me know if the answer makes sense

Comment: Did look at `?rowMeans`? Both `rowMeans` and `colMeans`  have an `na.rm` parameter, e.g.: `rowMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE)` should work

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the problem is that every mean from every row will be weighted identically. Yet that is problematic, since the one with NA has fewer observations and so should be weighted correspondingly.

Comment: Get your data into a tidy format. You should have a single `key` column that has values `1 2 3` instead of multiple columns named `1 2 3`. With your data in that format, this will be a trivial grouped mean. You can of course convert your result back to wide if that's how you want to present it.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the answer.I though about that, but didn't know how to do it. Do you know how to do that quickly?

Answer (score 4):

First we'll convert your factors to numeric so that the averages make sense:

```
df2[2:7] = lapply(df2[2:7], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))

library(dplyr
library(tidyr)
res = rbind(
  # convert to long format, melting each 1 2 3 column set
  gather(df2[1:4], key = key, value = value, -type),
  gather(df2[c(1, 5:7)],key = key, value = value, -type)
) %>%
    # do a grouped mean
    group_by(type, key) %>%
    summarize(mean = mean(value, na.rm = T))
res
# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: type [?]
# 
#     type   key     mean
#   <fctr> <chr>    <dbl>
# 1      a     1 3.500000
# 2      a     2 6.500000
# 3      a     3 3.000000
# 4      b     1 7.500000
# 5      b     2 2.666667
# 6      b     3 4.333333
```

That's how I would leave it, but if you want it wide you can use `spread`:

```
spread(res, key, mean)
# Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
# Groups: type [2]
# 
#     type   `1`      `2`      `3`
# * <fctr> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1      a   3.5 6.500000 3.000000
# 2      b   7.5 2.666667 4.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with your data in long format might be handy if you do work with larger matrices like this. This solution uses `data.table`. I also recommend avoiding numeric column names; R doesn't work well with them.

```
library(data.table)

df2 <- as.data.table(rbind(r1,r2,r3))
colnames(df2) <- c("type","x1","x2","x3","x1","x2","x3")

#melt long
df3 <- melt(df2, 
        id="type", 
        variable.name = "var", #default is "variable"
        value.name = "val", #default is "value"
        na.rm = T) #removes your NA values
df3 <- df3[, val := as.numeric(as.character(val))] #need to convert from character to numeric
df3 <- df3[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = "val", by=c("type","var")] #take mean by type and variable
#cast back to wide format to re-form your matrix
df3 <- dcast.data.table(df3, type ~ var, value.var="val") 
df3[, (colnames(df3)[-1]) := lapply(.SD, function(x) round(x,1)), .SDcols=colnames(df3)[-1]] #rounds your values to 1 decimal point
```